# Form Widget button in Odoo form

Tags: javascript, xml, odoo, odoo-10

I tried to add a button in Invoice form and i need to initiate a call in js

So i done Coding in Js as well as in XML Please find below.

In JS

```
odoo.define('test_module.print_button', function (require) {
"use strict";

var core = require('web.core');
var form_widget = require('web.form_widget');

var form_common = require('web.form_common');
var formats = require('web.formats');

var QWeb = core.qweb;
var _t = core._t;

form_widget.WidgetButton.include({
    on_click:function() {
        if(this.node.attrs.custom === "print"){
             console.log('Success');
        }
        else{
            this._super();
        }
    },  
});   
});
```

in XML i have inherited Account Invoice Form view

```
<odoo>
    <data>
        <record model="ir.ui.view" id="invoice_form_test">
            <field name="name">invoice.form.test</field>
            <field name="model">account.invoice</field>
            <field name="inherit_id" ref="account.invoice_form"/>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">

                <header position="inside">

                    <button type="action" string="Print Test"  icon="fa-print" custom="print" />


                </header>

            </field>
        </record>

    </data>
</odoo>
```

This won't working , while clicking it shows like

> TypeError: exec_workflow() takes exactly 4 arguments (3 given)

Do i need to add anything more to work it. Please comment.

Also Please suggest any way to pass button click to js from form view.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. you imported form widget wrongly.

   var form_widget = require('web.form_widgets'); // correct one